# php output performance impact

Tags: php, performance, nginx

I have page caching going on and I am trying to improve server response time and when I grab the cached page content via php, for whatever reason it takes about 800ms to output it to the browser.

```
require_once(PATH_TO_CACHED_FILE);
```

When I copy this exact same content and put it into a .html file, I get the same content in the browser in about 250ms.
I also get about 250ms when I switch the above `require_once` to this =>

```
echo 'a';
```

So with all this in mind - I'm thinking this is probably related to the buffer size as the bigger the buffer the longer it takes to output it)? Right? I mean - this is a huge difference - what could one do in order to more or less match outputting the content via php to simply loading html since both files do virtually the same thing (grab content / push to browser)?
Thanks!

btw: I also testing copying the output to a .php file (so it just echoed the cached HTML, there are no calculations done in this file) and it still takes ~800ms -- how can simply changing the extension from .php to .html make 500ms difference?

btw2: not sure if it's important, php is on nginx

Comment: What does `PATH_TO_CACHED_FILE` do inside?

Comment: Nothing, it's precached HTML content. When I copy this same content to a .php file, loading is still ~800ms. When I copy this same content to a .html file, loading is about 250ms.

Comment: Looks like you are adding some dynamic content in .php file to your HTML tags.

Comment: Are you passing any HTML table from the backend to the frontend with good amount of rows?

Comment: There's nothing dynamic actually. When I take the same content and paste it into .html I get ~250ms loading, when I paste it to .php it's ~800ms. Again - nothing dynamic going on.

Comment: Ok, can't say much as it is difficult to reproduce on my end.

Answer (score 0):

> what could one do in order to more or less match outputting the content via php to simply loading html since both files do virtually the same thing (grab content / push to browser)?

Nothing, see below.

> how can simply changing the extension from .php to .html make 500ms difference?

The PHP/PHP-FPM scripting engine is quite heavy compared to simple HTML access because it has to (potentially, based on current state) fork a worker process, do the necessary bootstrapping, load modules if they were not, parse the script and even in a simple HTML you `require`ing, it must parse it and look for `<?php` tags to process.

With direct HTML access, there is no PHP engine involved. Nothing of the above happens if you simply link/access your HTML file directly.

Aside from that, buffering can be an issue as well, if you use zlib on the PHP side.

If you must insist on some parent PHP code to be used to serve cache HTML files, then it probably makes sense to experiment with using [`readfile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) in lieu of `require`, as the former won't be subject to parsing the file content for PHP tags.

Otherwise, the best route to go with, if you already have complete HTML files (as in full page cache), is completely avoiding PHP invocation for them. This can be accomplished by using NGINX (or your webserver's of choice) rewrites to route requests directly to HTML-cache files, based on their presence (e.g. for NGINX this can be implemented using `try_files` directive).